# cada letra este en minuscula y mayuscula sucesivamente

Tags: java, netbeans

```
String frase = "Que todo fluja y que nada influya";
int largo = 0;
largo = frase.length();
for (int i = 1; i <= largo; i++) {
  if (i % largo == 0) {
    System.out.print(i.ToUpperCase());
  } else {
    System.out.print(i.ToLowerCase());
  }
```

Comment: no puedo agregar el codigo estructuradamente

Comment: `i.ToUpperCase()` ??? que es eso, estas colocando en mayúscula un numero???, aclara tu problema y explica lo que deseas obtener

Comment: necesito que cada letra de la frase vaya en minuscula y mayuscula sucesivamente

Comment: Podrias poner el resultado de tu `frase` para poder  entender mejor

Answer (score 1):

Una solucion seria resolviendo varios problemas que tiene tu codigo.

`i` es el indice, deberia servir para obtener cada caracter de la palabra asi:

```
 frase.charAt(i)
```

se debe obtener posiciones pares e impares se debe dividir el indice /2 y comprobar si es igual a 0

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class MinMayus {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String frase = "Que todo fluya y que nada influya";
    int largo = 0;
    largo = frase.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print((frase.charAt(i) + "").toUpperCase());
      } else {
        System.out.print((frase.charAt(i) + "").toLowerCase());
      }
    }
  }
}
```